# From protobuf object to general tree data structure

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, proto

I'm working on a project where I'm manipulating Google Protocol Buffers objects, with Protobuf v2 specs. I would like to convert the protobuf object into a general tree data structure, in order to do some manipulations (construct fields paths, and other operations)

I'm having hard time iterating over the objects in order to create my tree. I don't know if there's a easy way to iterate over object messages (and their nested messages), and get type and value?

Oh. last but not least, I need to handle this in C++

thank you